# Get Positions of Images in an Excel table in terms or Row ID and Column ID using Office Scripts

Tags: excel, typescript, excel-formula, office-scripts

I have an excel sheet downloaded from a 3rd party API which has got a image column with images in each row. The image object is named as "Picture 1" on every image under the image column. Now I would like to generate the base64 string of this image so that I can use this image in other data sources like SharePoint, SQL Server etc. I figured out how to convert it to base 64. The problem I have is I am unable to get the position of this image in each row so I can define the base64 string of this image in the same row on a new column called "base64 text". I understood getRange function is not supported for images, charts or shapes. But how do I get the position of the image now? I tried searching all over but couldn't find anything. Here are the steps I would like to do using office script.

1. Get Row number of the image. Name the object with row number like "Picture 1" for row 1, "Picture 2" for row 2.
2. Once I have the row number, I would like to get the shape or image at this position and get base64 text of this image under "base64 text" column.
3. Use this base64 string in other data sources.

Please help me with the directions. Thanks a lot in advance.

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: In office 365 you can directly reference the cell of the picture to show it, so if you know the row # you can use `=index([PictureColumn,row#)`, otherwise you could use the `linked picture` option and make that dynamical.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I have an "Image" column, "base64" column. How do I get base64 string of the image using Office script? or how do I reference this image using the row number using office script?

Comment: I'm not talking about office script, simply referencing the cell with the embedded picture (Office 365) using =IMAGE() https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-function-7e112975-5e52-4f2a-b9da-1d913d51f5d5 In older excel copy any of the picture cells and paste special (linked picture) and change the reference to INDEX of the range containing the pictures with the row number you already calculated).
Since you didn't post any sample data I can't post an actual answer that would make sense.

Comment: This needs to be automated as we have to process thousands of excel rows and on a schedule basis. So doing anything manual is not feasible.

Comment: Linked picture can hold INDEX MATCH. You can lookup the string in B:B and show A:A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Office Script doesn't provide a method to get topleft cell of shape.
- Create a UDF to get topleft cell
- Convert image to Base64 string and write to the next column

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let shpObjects = selectedSheet.getShapes();
    shpObjects.forEach(shp => {
        let anchorCell: ExcelScript.Range = getTopLeftCell(shp, selectedSheet);
        if (anchorCell) {
            anchorCell.getOffsetRange(0, 1).setValue(shp.getImageAsBase64(ExcelScript.PictureFormat.png));
            shp.setName("Picture_" + (anchorCell.getRowIndex().valueOf() + 1));
        }
    })
}

function getTopLeftCell(shpObject: ExcelScript.Shape,
    shtObject: ExcelScript.Worksheet): ExcelScript.Range {
    // Define search Range, modify as needed
    const max_rows = 100;
    const max_cols = 100;
    const shpTop = shpObject.getTop();
    const shpLeft = shpObject.getLeft();
    let topLeftCell: ExcelScript.Range;
    for (let row = 0; row < max_rows; row++) {
        let cellCur = shtObject.getCell(row, 0).getTop();
        let cellNext = shtObject.getCell(row + 1, 0).getTop();
        if (shpTop >= cellCur && shpTop <= cellNext) {
            for (let col = 0; col < max_cols; col++) {
                let cellCur = shtObject.getCell(0, col).getLeft();
                let cellNext = shtObject.getCell(0, col + 1).getLeft();
                if (shpLeft >= cellCur && shpLeft <= cellNext) {
                    topLeftCell = shtObject.getCell(row, col);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return topLeftCell;
}
```

[image]

---

- Add a vertical margin to locate the desired top-left cell. This adjustment should resolve the overlap issue with the cell's upper border, as shown in the screenshot provided by OP.

```
function getTopLeftCell(shpObject: ExcelScript.Shape,
    shtObject: ExcelScript.Worksheet): ExcelScript.Range {
    // Define search Range, modify as needed
    const max_rows = 100;
    const max_cols = 100;
    const vertical_margin = 3; // modify as needed
    const shpTop = shpObject.getTop();
    const shpLeft = shpObject.getLeft();
    let topLeftCell: ExcelScript.Range;
    for (let row = 0; row < max_rows; row++) {
        let cellCur = shtObject.getCell(row, 0).getTop() - vertical_margin;
        let cellNext = shtObject.getCell(row + 1, 0).getTop() - vertical_margin;
        if (shpTop >= cellCur && shpTop <= cellNext) {
            for (let col = 0; col < max_cols; col++) {
                let cellCur = shtObject.getCell(0, col).getLeft();
                let cellNext = shtObject.getCell(0, col + 1).getLeft();
                if (shpLeft >= cellCur && shpLeft <= cellNext) {
                    topLeftCell = shtObject.getCell(row, col);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return topLeftCell;
}
```

Comment: this is working beautifully except
1. One of the images' base64 string is overwriting my header. Image reference in the original post as am unable to attach here in the comment.
2. What if my base64 string column is not next to my image column? It can be the last column in my table or anywhere. Where do I adjust your code for that.

Thank you for putting all the effort for this. Really grateful for you. Excuse for my silly questions as I am very beginner in office scripts and started understanding slowly.

Comment: All base64 result shift up  a cell. I guess the image is overlap with cell upper boarder. e.g. the 1st image's top left cell must be A1. Please check it with VBA code:  `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).TopLeftCell.Address`

Comment: Add a vertical margin to locate the desired topleft cell, please try the revised code.

Comment: Thank you so much @taller. That has fixed the problem. It might take sometime for me to understand your code, but I will sit on it. I at least managed to move the base64 string to different column using getOffsetRange. I am so much thankful to you.